# How to get firestore reference type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have the following code:

```
import { DocumentReference } from '@firebase/firestore-types'

export type Recipe = {
  author: string
  title: string
  ingredients: {
    quantity: number
    ingredient: DocumentReference["path"]
  }[]
  instructions: string[]
}

export const getAllRecipes = async() => {
  const snapshot = await db.collection('recipes').get()
  const data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
  return data
}



const recipes: Recipe[]  = await getAllRecipes()
```

I for some reason can't seem to get the type right for the ingredients.
The error I got is:

`Error: Error serializing .recipes[0].ingredients[0].ingredient returned from getStaticProps in "/".`

What is the way to define the type on array of references from `firestore` in `typescript`?

Also, if I do (just for debugging)

```
export const getAllRecipes = async() => {
  const snapshot = await db.collection('recipes').get()
  const data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
    const docData = doc.data()
    const {ingredients} = docData
    ingredients.map((ingredient: DocumentReference) => {
      const jsonIngredient = ingredient.path
      console.log(jsonIngredient) 
    })
    return docData
  })
  return data
}
```

Why do I get path is undefined?
[image]

[image]

Comment: What line of code generates that error?  I don't see any code that serializes anything at all. I also don't see where you are using the Recipes type.  I suggest editing the question to add all of the relevant code, as well as explain what you expect the code to do instead of generate this error.

Comment: @DougStevenson Added more code. However, can just be a simple call which define type, don't need to write it out, given there is a call function already.  For example const recipes: Recipes[]  = await getAllRecipes()

Comment: This is all the code you're running?  I still don't see any serialization.  What line of code causes the error?

Comment: @DougStevenson the last line, note that the tag is including Nextjs, so error coming from the call await getAllRecipes() and serialised from getStaticProps. I updated the full error msg

Comment: What do your documents look like?  That would be the actual data, right?

Comment: @DougStevenson The documents look as defined in the type Recipe, except the ingredients is the array of object references, I added a snapshot above

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that the default toJSON serialization of a DocumentReference object (which is a complex object with references to other Firestore objects) just isn't going to work the way you want.  If you want the caller to have a DocumentReference, you're going to have to convert each one into a string path using its [path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#path) property, then rebuild the path into a reference using [Firestore.doc(path)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#doc).  The TypeScript type doesn't matter at all - it is simply a layer of understanding around core set of objects.

Comment: How can I get the path? As I put the above code, I didnt get the paths, they are for some reason undefined?

Comment: As I linked in my answer, if you have a DocumentReference object, you can use its path propery.  I can't explain why you have an undefined value somewhere.  That wouldn't event serialize at all.  You'll have to dig into the document snapshot and get to the actual reference objects somehow.